# Checking for user input without using "if" statement?

Tags: python, computer-science

For my homework assignment, I'm trying to think of a way to check for user input without using the if statement.

This would be how the algorithm is implemented with an "if" statement

```
if userInput == "books":
    printBooks()
else:
    addBooks()
```

Is there a way to implement the same thing without using an if statement?

Comment: Why? Does your homework ask for you to do this?

Comment: yea, it's a requirement.

"Don't use any if statement to select the functions.Take advantage of the fact that functions are first class objects in Python."

Answer (score 1):

If you just do not want to see `if` in the code, this is the way to do:

```
func = {"book": printBooks}
func.get(userInput, addBooks)()
```

You put function as an object to a dict, retrieve it based on user input as the key, with a default fallback, then call the function.

And, yes, this is a bad approach in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever see a need for this, but:

```
(addBooks, printBooks)[userInput == "books"]()
```

Answer (score -1):

For python you can use like this
bookData = printBooks() if userInput == "books" else addBooks()

Comment: "without using “if” statement"